# sh: husky: command not found

Tags: node.js, git, npm, husky, git-husky

I've setup a node project with husky but when my collegue tries to run `npm install` on his Mac he gets the following error :

```
noa-be@1.0.0 prepare
husky install

sh: husky: command not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/X/Desktop/Workspace/project
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c husky install

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/X/.npm/_logs/2021-04-12T13_07_25_842Z-debug.log
```

These are the relevant package.json parts:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "prepare": "husky install"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "husky": "^5.2.0",
    }
}
```

I thought this would be enough for husky to be installed when running `npm install`, but it's not. What am I missing?

Comment: This error is also thrown by `npm ci` if the `NODE_ENV` is set to "production" pre-install

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been able to solve the problem by upgrading to latest Husky version (7.0.1, from 5.2.0).

Git was also helpful, and told me that the files weren't executables. (Git V 2.24.1)

So I give them executable rights :

```
chmod +x PATH_TO_HUSKY_FILE
```

You'll need to execute this command for every hooks

Answer (score 178):

If you are using `nvm`, you might want to create a file called `.huskyrc` in your `home` directory and add the following lines of code to it:

`~/.huskyrc`

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to install husky on the devDependencies.

Comment: Does this apply to Windows? If so, where is this `home` file exactly?

Comment: I go the following error message when trying to commit from IntelliJ (worked fine directly from terminal): `.husky/pre-commit: 4: npm: not found`.
Your suggestion fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Commits were working fine for me using CLI, but Tower.app was complaining with an error. After I added this Tower was able to commit.

Comment: Please explain how this answers the original question, because as far as I can tell this is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 28):

I was struggling with the same exact problem for hours. Finally, I could install dependencies and start working on my project by doing this:

1. Temporarily remove the `"prepare": "husky install"` script from the package.json file.
2. Run `npm i` (`npm install`). Dependencies installed successfuly.
3. Add again the `"prepare"` script that you removed in step 1.
4. Run again `npm i` to install the husky git hooks, so husky can do its job from now on.

Comment: Thank you so much. Any idea the reasoning behind why we have to remove prepare and why husky isn't built in a way to avoid this?

Comment: Incredible, but this works.

Answer (score 24):

Faced this issue in `Github Desktop`.

solved it by quit `Github Desktop` and re-open it.

Answer (score 19):

It worked in my terminal but not in VSCode version control. So had to force quite the vscode app and restarting it worked.

Comment: Yep, this fixed it in vscode.  Why...like most broken things, it doesn't pay to figure it out.

Comment: It fixed in my case, MacOS Ventura M2, zsh (oh-my-zsh) with fnm and starship.

Comment: +1 since it worked in my Ubuntu terminal even though it's not working in VSC. Quitting and opening VSC didn't help. But at least I know that lint-staged and husky can work on my system if I don't use VSC.

Comment: Force quitting VS Code and restarting it fixed it for me too... Weird...
Intel Mac OS Catalina, zsh (oh-my-zsh)

Answer (score 9):

I believe it could be version specific issue. Install version 6, `npm i husky@6.0.0 --save-dev`, and it should work as the [husky doc](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/) says.

Apparently, when I did `npm i husky --save-dev`, it was installing `"husky": "^0.8.1"` for me for some strange reason, giving me the exact same error: `sh: husky: command not found`.

**Method 1:**

Update manually, in your `package.json`:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "prepare": "husky install",
        "create-hook": "husky add .husky/pre-commit \"npm test\"",
    }
}
```

Then, run `npm run prepare && npm run create-hook`.

It should create `.husky` directory with `.pre-commit` file in it.

**Method 2:**

`npx husky install`

`npm set-script prepare "husky install"`

`npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npm test"`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by providing an explicit location for husky

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "node_modules/.bin/husky-run install"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

What `.huskyrc` needs to do is:

1. Check if there is a `.nvmrc` file in the working directory
2. Run the `nvm.sh` script
3. Run `nvm use`, so all node related executables (eg: `yarn`) will be ready to use

Thus, here is a version of `.huskyrc` that fulfil those requisites:

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

if [ -f .nvmrc ] && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ];
then
  . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
  nvm use
fi;
```

Comment: Instead of adding those to my `~/.huskyrc`, I added it directly to the `project/.husky/pre-commit` & `project/.husky/pre-push` since my team is also using `nvm`.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're facing this issue while installing the production dependencies you can use this solution

```bash
npm set-script prepare '' && npm install --omit=dev
```

Comment: This is good for production because it bypasses the unnecessary husky setup

Answer (score 2):

For peoples in Windows using WebStorm, Gitkraken etc... if you encounter this error, try to setup C:\Program Files\Git\bin for Path in Environment Variables System. It may help you. Do not forget to restart IDE/terminal after it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [Using Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/docs/getting-started)

When I upgraded husky from version 4 to 8 there was information todo first pre commit manually. For this purpose `pre-commit` bash script was generated in `.husky` directory.

What I had todo was simply run the command included in this file:

```bash
lerna run precommit --concurrency 2 --stream
```